# Using IHostedService to check a DB

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

I want to create a service that runs in the background all the time. This service will be always checking a table in my DB.
I'm doing it with asp.net core 2.1 using `IHostedService` and my problem is: If I use `AddSingleton` I cant inject the `DBContext` on the `Repository`, and if I use `AddScoped` I cant inject the `HostedService`.

Is there some way of fix this, or a better way of do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [link](https://thinkrethink.net/2018/07/12/injecting-a-scoped-service-into-ihostedservice/) helped me a lot.

Injecting `IServiceScopeFactory` inside the `HostedService` could provide the instances nedded solving the problem. Not sure if it is the better way to do it. If you guys know a better way of doing this leave a comment :)

Here is the code.

**HostedService Implementation:**

```
public class TestService : HostedService
{
    private readonly IServiceScopeFactory _serviceScopeFactory;

    public TestService(IServiceScopeFactory serviceScopeFactory)
    {
        _serviceScopeFactory = serviceScopeFactory;          
    }

    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        using (var scope = _serviceScopeFactory.CreateScope())
        {
            IMyService myScopedService = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IMyService>();

            while (!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                await myScopedService.Execute();
                await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5), cancellationToken);
            }
        }

    }
}
```